# Finding and displaying Laplace or Z transform ROC(region of convergence) using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, z-transform, laplace-transform

Is there any way, we can use MATLAB for finding and displaying Laplace or Z transform Region of convergence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab can only compute expressions for the uni-lateral (one-sided) versions of the Laplace transform and Z-transform. It doesn't explicitly determine the ROCs, but since both transforms are uni-lateral, there's only one possible choice for the ROCs: let $p_k$ be the poles of the Laplace or Z-transform. The ROCs are given by
$$\textrm{Laplace transform:}\quad\textrm{Re}\{s\}>\max_k\textrm{Re}\{p_k\}$$
$$\textrm{Z-transform:}\quad |z|>\max_k|p_k|$$

I.e., for the (uni-lateral) Laplace transform the ROC is a right half-plane, to the right of the right-most pole, and for the (uni-lateral) Z-transform, the ROC is the region outside the circle (centered at the origin) with its radius equal to the maximum pole magnitude.

Comment: Some good exposition [here](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electrical_Engineering/Signal_Processing_and_Modeling/Signals_and_Systems_(Baraniuk_et_al.)/12%3A_Z-Transform_and_Discrete_Time_System_Design/12.06%3A_Region_of_Convergence_for_the_Z-Transform) about when the ROC for the two-sided transforms might be elsewhere than the ones Matt correctly gives for the one-sided transforms done by Matlab.

Comment: As you wrote ''for the (uni-lateral) Laplace transform the ROC is a right half-plane, to the right of the right-most pole" and also it is case in reality but how can we show/display it in MATLAB just like in theory books we have hatched type area (having diagonal lines)representing Region of convergence